# why does explain show 'Using index condition'?

Tags: optimization, mariadb

I am studying Using index condition in mariadb

This is for Centos7 and running Mariadb 10.2

this is my SQL.

create index

```
create index ixnn_product__updated_at
    on product (updated_at);
```

explain

```
explain extended
select * from product
where updated_at BETWEEN '2018-06-10 00:00:00' AND '2019-06-10 23:59:59'
```

result

```
          id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: product
         type: range
possible_keys: ixnn_product__updated_at
          key: ixnn_product__updated_at
      key_len: 5
          ref: NULL
         rows: 2431232
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index condition
```

I expected a using index in extra but i saw Using index condition

So I added test.

explain

```
explain extended 
select updated_at from product
 where updated_at BETWEEN '2018-06-10 00:00:00' AND '2019-06-10 23:59:59'
```

result

```
          id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: product
         type: range
possible_keys: ixnn_product__updated_at
          key: ixnn_product__updated_at
      key_len: 5
          ref: NULL
         rows: 2431232
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where; Using index
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

`Using index condition` and `Using index` are *unrelated* optimizations.  (It's unfortunate that the names are so close.)

`Using index condition` can be researched via its other names:  `ICP` or `Index Condition Pushdown`.  It is a speedup over previously where the Engine (eg, InnoDB) would pass the row back to the "Handler".  With ICP, the Engine does the test (against `updated_at` in your case).

`Using index` means that the index is "covering".  That means that *all* the columns needed from the table exist in the index being used.  And that implies that the query can be performed entirely in the index's BTree, without having to reach over into the data's Btree.  Your first `SELECT` needs all the columns (`*`); your second needs only `updated_at`, so it is "covering".

(ICP was added to MariaDB in 5.3; to Mysql in 5.6.)

Comment: thank you for answer. i think first query is not ICP. becuase
there are no other where conditions.

Comment: @hoyeonUm - I agree that it seems 'wrong'.  Please provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` (if it is available) and the ["optimizer trace"](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#optimizer_trace)

Comment: @RickJames-  `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON` 
first query result 
`"index_condition": "product.updated_at between '2018-06-10 00:00:00' and '2019-06-10 23:59:59'"`

second query result 
`"attached_condition": "product.updated_at between '2018-06-10 00:00:00' and '2019-06-10 23:59:59'","using_index": true`

Unfortunatly `optimizer trace` not support. start with MariaDB 10.4.3.

[optimizer trace](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/optimizer-trace/)